# In android when i try to run my project it says 'No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'?

Tags: android

'No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
here is the error ->>><style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
```

Answer (score 0):

-->open android SDK manager,make sure that Android Support Library is installed..

-->After that the AppCompat Can be found at

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

-->You need to reference this AppCompat in your android project.

-->Import the library to eclipse.
-->Right click on your android project. Goto Properties. goto andorid. Click Add Library and  reference the same.
-->Clean and Rebuild your project

Comment: I did this but no difference.The error is still there.Why is that?